# Why is my started service being destroyed?

Tags: android, android-activity, service, android-service

I `startService()` a service and then `bindService()` it from the same activity. Now, I'm pretty sure in the activity lifecycle that it doesn't matter if the activity is paused, stopped, or destroyed, I'm 90% sure my service persists (which is what I want). But when I press the square button (bring up the list of recent apps) and swipe the app to close it, I believe the service is paused, if not destroyed. Is this just what happens when you close an app in this fashion? And is there a way to do some code from the service before it happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Services are killed when the user swipes the app from recents.  But if `onStartCommand(...)` returned `START_STICKY`, they will be restarted a few seconds later.  I consider it a bug that they are killed and restarted; they should either not be killed, or killed and not restarted.  I'm not sure if Google agrees.

Before the service is killed, it will get a call to [onTaskRemoved(...)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onTaskRemoved%28android.content.Intent%29).

Comment: Thank you for the information. It is enough to solve my problem. However, I do have a random hypothetical. If I do return START_STICKY, but in `onTaskRemoved()` I have a stopSelf() command, what would happen?

Comment: @grey00 I'd guess it would not be restarted, but you'll have to try it yourself.